# Checking change in form field before executing AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form on my view page.. whenever form  populate on the page ..it is filled with old values ... I mean input box and check-box have old values ... and then I am posting form through ajax..after posting if values successfully saved into database I am showing the message that information updated successfully or vice versa...so the problem is now that if for example user do not change anything,the form values are same in the text-boxes then when user pressed save button i don't want to show him that information has updated as he didn't do anything .. I want to ask if that possible in java script ...or should i have to query into the database and check that whether values are same or not? and the other thing that if it can be possible that button remains disable until he do some changes in any of the form field...

I am not writing the whole code just the `javascript` part

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password-check').val();
    var oldpassword = $('#oldpassword').val();
    var timezone = $('#UserinfoTimezone').val();
    var alternate_email = $('#alternate_email').val();
    //var newsletter = $('#newsletter').val();

    var form_data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password-check').val(),
        oldpassword: $('#oldpassword').val(),
        timezone: $('#UserinfoTimezone').val(),
        alternate_email: $('#alternate_email').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:form_data,
        url:"https:/localhost/settings/",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("successfully data saved"):
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the values while you would have populated the fields in the form... Otherwise you can use a flag variable which can be given a value in .change() function of each field and that value can be checked on submit of the form.. But I guess the first option will be more efficient as the flag will be set even if the user edits the field and enters the same value again...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the old values in the JavaScript and compare them against the current values in the submit handler. If nothing changed, don't `POST`.

And yes, you can also have the save button disabled initially and attach `onChange` handlers to the form fields that enable the save button when the contents of those fields change.

Answer (score 0):

On ajax submit copy input values to some attribute, so you know last sent data.

```
$('#form input').each(function() {

 $(this).data('last-ajax-value', $(this).val());

});
```

When invoking second ajax submit you can check if these values match and make some decision.

```
var someValueDiffers = false;

$('#form input').each(function() {

 if($(this).data('last-ajax-value') != $(this).val())
  someValueDiffers = true;

});

if(someValueDiffers)
 // Form changed
else
 // Form is the same
```

Comment: this.defaultValue=this.value sounds simpler to me. If you set the data attribute, use `.data("last-ajax-value",this.value)` instead of attr

Comment: IMO it's clearer to use data attr, it's not about default value of the input, but about last posted value. I think form will be posted multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but defaultValue makes more sense since if we had not uset ajax, we could have set the field values on the server

Comment: If the user uses the same value for input fields again, then this logic will  not allow them to save the values.

Comment: Which is what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

On the page load you can get all the input element values and hold them in seperate global variables. When you submit the form check the current input values with old one that you have saved. If any one is not equal, user has changed the form and you can submit it.

```
var init_name = "";
var submit_flag   = false;
$(document).ready( function () {

 var init_name = $('#name').val();

 $("#submit").click(function(e){ 

     var name = $('#name').val();

     if(name == init_name) {

       // user has not changed
       submit_flag = false;
     } else {
       submit_flag = true;
     }
     if(submit_flag) {
        // call the ajax
     }
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After submit the ajax values you need to clear the input field values.

Place this code instead of your success:

```
 ...
    success: function(data){
    alert("successfully data saved"):
     $('#myformid').find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
      $('#myformid').find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
     .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve that. Diseable the submit button. Eneable it if a change is made on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can unset the input values when page gets loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input").each(function(){
      $(this).val() = '';
   });
});
```

Comment: That way the user can enter the same stuff and it will be saved again